# android socket code

Tags: android, sockets

Why can't a socket be open with this code:

```
                try {
                    Connect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
                    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2",54628);
                    DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(cmd.getBytes(), cmd.length(), address);
                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    socket.send(request);
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    System.out.print("SSSS");
                }
```

but it does work when I do:

```
    clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.1.2",54635); 
    Text.append( "\n created a socket");
```

---

Error logs:

```
05-24 23:04:58.497: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(95): unknown stream type
05-24 23:05:10.787: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(95): unknown stream type
05-24 23:05:10.787: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(95): unknown stream type
05-24 23:05:10.787: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(95): unknown stream type
05-24 23:05:10.787: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(95): unknown stream type
```

Comment: maybe because the port is different?

Comment: You asked 13 question and didn't accept just one of them. And you think someone is going to help you on this?

Comment: @ Mighuel no the same port is to the servers

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider going back over your other questions and accepting answers if they worked for you. You are less likely to get help with 0% accept rate.

Change your System.out.print() statement to e.printStackTrace(); Then run the app and copy the output from your Logcat and paste it in your question. That will help us understand what is actually going wrong.